# Global COUNTIF on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I would like to **count every occurrence** of a string in an **entire worksheet**.

I know that this function permit to count, but on a specific range:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange,myword)
```

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WorkSheets("Sheet1").Cells,"toad")` will count all the `toad`s in the whole worksheet on `Sheet1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I posted Scott Craner's answer which does the job !*

```
 WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WorkSheets("Sheet1").Cells,"toad")
```

will count the number of cells with `toad` in the whole worksheet on Sheet1